# Nebular - When I try to change tab using selectedTab, it cant read disabled property

Tags: angular, typescript, nebular

When I try to change tab, using this function:

```
  public consultarCNPJDefinido(cnpjDefinido: string) {
    this.cnpj = cnpjDefinido;
    this.AtivarTabConsulta();
    this.consultarCNPJ();
    this.AtivarTabCnpj();
  }
```

these are the functions being called

```
  AtivarTabConsulta() {
    console.log(this.consultastab)
    this.tabselect.selectTab(this.consultastab);
  }

  public AtivarTabCnpj() {
    this.tabset.selectTab(this.cnpjtab);
  }

  public AtivarTabCpf() {
    this.tabset.selectTab(this.cpftab);
  }
```

So, the problem is, I get this error
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNUd8.png)

Then when I see the object nebular is trying to read, it gives me these properties
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MA98q.png)

As you can see, it cant read because its not a property.
Then I found inside nebular nodemodules, this declaration

```
selectTab(selectedTab) {
        if (!selectedTab.disabled) {
            this.tabs.forEach(tab => tab.active = tab === selectedTab);
            this.changeTab.emit(selectedTab);
        }
    }
```

and I think this is killing my function.

I tried changing the function and the way I call it but no success

Comment: Please show the definition of your tabs - e.g - `consultastab`, `cnpjtab`